# Get elements from a numpy array using another array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array, `a`, of shape `(2, 5, 2)`. I need to get 2 elements from the array at locations `[0, 1, 0]` and `[1, 3, 0]`. To retrieve these elements, I have an array, `b`, with entries `[1, 3]`. When I use `a[:,b]`, I get `2x2` matrix (as expected). How can I change the indexing to return the required vector instead? Following is an MWE.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.random.randn(2, 5, 2)
b = np.random.randint(0, 5, 2)

c = a[:, b]
c.shape  # prints (2, 2), while I only need a[0, b[0]] and a[1, b[1]].
```

PS: This problem can be solved using a `for` loop. However in my actual code the index is in the order of 1000 and therefore not feasible.

Comment: Does `c = a[np.arange(a.shape[0]), b]` do what you want?

Comment: @hilberts_drinking_problem, yes indeed, that solves my problem. Please put it down as an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, one can do `c = a[np.arange(a.shape[0]), b]` to obtain the required result.